# Problem with formula for cylindrical chandelier problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, angular-momentum, rotation, angular-velocity

**The problem says:**

*A cylindrical chandelier is hung on a wire and when it rotates around its siege an angle $\theta$ the twisting moment acting on it is $\tau$ = $−\theta$. The moment of inertia is unitary and its angular velocity in the equilibrium position is unitary. Calculate the maximum twist angle $\theta_0$, ...*

**And the suggested solution is:**

*From the conservation of mechanical energy:
$\frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{2}\theta_0^2$* so $\theta_0 = 1$

But where does this formula came from?

Comment: It would be more accurate to say "From the work energy theorem" instead of "conservation of mechanical energy". You can find the KE at $\theta =0$ and $\theta = \theta_0$, and the work done by the twisting moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The chandelier is in an SHM since $\tau=-\theta$, where $\kappa=1$. Since the kinetic energy in the equilibrium position equals the potential energy at the amplitude position, $\frac12I\omega^2=\frac12\kappa\theta_0^2$.

Comment: Then why $I \omega^2 = 1$?

Comment: It is given that $I=1$kgm$^2$ and $\omega=1$rad/s at the equilibrium position.